# How to access the attributes of a class in sencha.........?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

i'm very new to sencha.i have a bit problem in accessing the data from framework..

what i planned is to access the attribute "selectedIndex" from the class Ext.Picker.Slot

so that i can place it the index.js file and loop the "selectedIndex" attribute so that i can create a rotating effect to my list , i'm trying to dynamically change the value of "selectedIndex" so that my list seems to be rotating so please do help me........

Thankyou,
........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.Picker is not an extjs class. You should provide more info so I can help you. In any way there must be a method which puts selectedIndex to desired value. Js don't have properties like in other OOP languages. It's just a variable. Changing value of it don't do any "action". So, there must be method which do the "action" and sets selectedIndex.